# MySql query: Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple select statement with a where clause on my php file like so:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("hostname", "user", "pw", "db");    
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to mySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$getTitle = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title FROM tblTitle WHERE category='" .$col."'") or die("ERROR: ". mysqli_error($con));
```

I've changed my code as suggested and added the quotation mark on my variable but now I'm getting an internal server error at the $getTitle line. Am I doing something wrong here? I can't print the error so I can't point out what's going on.

UPDATE: As suggested, I've used var dump on $getTitle and here's the message I got.

object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: single quote around `$col` and double quote around the complete query

Comment: Please `var_dump($getTitle)` and print output here

Answer (score 3):

`$col` should be within quote, otherwise it seems like `category=music` and Mysql assumes that `music` is a column.

If you are in PHP, use

```
"Select title from tblTitle where category='".$col."'";
```

or

```
"Select title from tblTitle where category='$col'";
```

Comment: So I gave this a try, however now I'm getting a 500 internal server error and I can't pinpoint what's going on. I can't show the php errors.

Comment: `"Select title from tblTitle where category='$col'";` will fail to evaluate $col if you put it in single quote. PHP will consider it as constant.

Comment: I've updated my code to include the part where I'm getting the error and that doesn't really have that much php.

Comment: Your connection has problem . use `if (!$con) {
    die('Failed to connect to mySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}`. `mysqli_connet_errno()` has no parameter.

Answer (score 1):

use like this in php `"Select title from tblTitle where category=".$col;`

Comment: So I gave this a try and I'm getting an internal server error and I have no idea what's causing it.

Comment: u have problem with settings not with coding for sure!

Answer (score 1):

That means you are having problem with your incorrect permission settings. Please first you check your database as well as file permission.If you are in Linux please change file permission to 644.have a look at your .htaccess file.There must be some error while settings.I think this will resolve your issue.Give it a try. Happy coding :)